# PHP How to remove all value after 4 comma in php

Tags: javascript, php

Hi there i have a value `1,2,3,4,5,6,7` and i want to change this value into `1,2,3,4` i don't want any value after 4 in my php code,

if you have any idea how to done it with `PHP or Javascript`

Comment: There a few ways. What have you tried yourself?

Comment: `str_replace, preg_replace` i have already tryed

Comment: Edit the question to add the code which you have tried already

Comment: if it is string then try `echo substr("1,2,3,4,5,6,7",0,7);`

Comment: `preg_replace('/4,.+$/', '4', $string)`  For [Example](https://regex101.com/r/LcsvE0/1)

Comment: `value after 4` the number or `value after 4 commas`?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix hmm .. good question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you provided no efforts in writing code, here's a oneliner for you to understand:

```
echo implode(',', array_slice(explode(',', '1,2,3,4,5,6,7', 4 + 1), 0, 4));
```

Fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/L4L4S).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `preg_replace` in PHP:

```
$string = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
echo preg_replace('/^(([^,]+,){3}[^,]).*$/', '$1', $string);
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4
```

Similarly in Javascript:

```js
const string = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
console.log(string.replace(/^(([^,]+,){3}[^,]).*$/, '$1'));
```